# How can I keep restarting my worker threads over and over again?

Tags: puppeteer, worker

I have a small puppeteer scraping tool. I spawn my workers using an api call in the browser so it launches the appropriate chrome profile right away. I have about 3 running but sometimes there is an error and one of the browsers will close. How can I keep restarting the worker over and over after it closes? Before I would use 'forever' when I was only running one browser but now I need it for multiple and not sure how I can incorporate that.

Here is my code:

index.js

```js
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);

app.route("/api/chrome").get((request, response) => {
  worker(request.query.profile, {
    //here you can send any additional data to the worker thread
  });

  return response.status(200).send("booting the browser");
});

function worker(profile, data = {}) {
  const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", {
    workerData: {
      ...data,
      profile: profile,
    },
  });

  worker.profile = profile;

  worker.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log(`message back from worker: ${message}`);
  });

  worker.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  worker.on("exit", (code) => {
    console.log(`Worker exited - ${code} ++ ${worker.profile}`);
  });

  return worker;
}

http.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`http server started on 127.0.0.1:8000`);
});
```

worker.js

```js
let { workerData, parentPort } = require("worker_threads");

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
    ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
    args: [
      "--remote-debugging-port=9444",
      "--user-data-dir=D:/chrome-profiles/" + workerData.profile,
      "--no-first-run",
      "--no-default-browser-check",
      `--window-size=1920,1080`,
    ],
  });

  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));

  const pages = await browser.pages();
  const page = pages[0];


  await page.goto("https://www.google/");
```

I've tried forever but I couldn't get it to work properly.